# Gnuplot with SI-prefixes: How do I get gnuplot not to display decimal zeros?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting wavelength with a custom format for `xtics` in Gnuplot. What I want to achive are `xtics` like this:

> 200nm, 400nm, 600nm, 800nm, 1um, 1.2 um, 1.4um

I'm almost there with this code:

```
set xlabel "Wavelenth"
set format x "%3.1s%cm"
set xrange [1e-8:1.5e-6]

plot x lw 3
```

However, because of the `%3.1s`, Gnuplot appends a useless `.0`, where none is necessary. So Gnuplot's `xtics` in aboves range are:

> 200.0nm, 400.0nm, 600.0nm, 800.0nm, 1um, 1.2 um, 1.4um

That widens the `tics`, which is ugly. I can't figure out how to specify width and precision so that decimal places that are all zero are not displayed. Is there a way?

[image: unwanted digits]

Comment: Have you simply tried `%s%cm`? Otherwise I don't think you can achieve that without manually setting the labels with `set for [...] xtics add ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible other than specifying the tics manually:

```
set xtics ("200nm" 2e-7, "400nm" 4e-7, "600nm" 6e-7, "800nm" 8e-7, "1.2um" 1.2e-6, "1.4um" 1.4e-6)
```

If you use the postscript terminal, you me be able cut away the ".0nm" with sed

```
set term postscript eps
set out 'plot.eps'
set xlabel "Wavelenth"
set format x "%3.1s%cm"
set xrange [1e-8:1.5e-6]
plot x lw 3
set output
!sed  -i 's/\.0nm/nm/g' plot.eps
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but in any case you must finish the output with `set output` before calling `sed`

Comment: @Christoph Didn't know that, the script worked fine before (maybe not always), so I added the line now in the answer